# concatenating const and dynamic strings in c++

Tags: c++, string

I have a class that conjugate verbs, that class uses constant strings and other strings to return its result, gcc builds it correctly  but I get runtime error when calling it

constant strings class

ArabicHarakat.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace sarf{

class ArabicHarakat
{
public:

    static const wstring FATHA ;

    static const wstring DAMMA ;

    static const wstring KASRA ;

    static const wstring SKOON  ;

    static const wstring SHADDA ;

};

}
```

ArabicHarakat.cpp

```
#include "ArabicHarakat.h"

namespace sarf{


const wstring ArabicHarakat::FATHA = L"َ";

const wstring ArabicHarakat::DAMMA = L"ُ";

const wstring ArabicHarakat::KASRA = L"ِ";

const wstring ArabicHarakat::SKOON  = L"ْ";

const wstring ArabicHarakat::SHADDA = L"ّ";

}
```

my class uses another class called root which returns strings to be used in conjugation

and the function that do the conjugate verbs is:

```
wstring  AugmentedActivePastVerb::ConjugateInFormula8()
{
    return L"ت"+ArabicHarakat::FATHA+root->getC1()+ArabicHarakat::FATHA+root->getC2()+ArabicHarakat::SHADDA+ArabicHarakat::FATHA+root->getC3()+lastDpa+connectedPronoun;
}
```

so, I have const strings ArabicHarakat::FATHA, L"XXX" and so on and dynamic strings returned by root.getCX()

the code above get compiled correctly, but in runtime I get Segmentation fault error

I hope you can help
thanks in advance

call stack from codeblocks

```
#0 ??   sarf::verb::trilateral::augmented::AugmentedActivePastVerb::ConjugateInFormula8 (this=0x69d580) (/home/yasser/projects/testv3z_augmented/verb/trilateral/augmented/active/AugmentedActivePastVerb.cpp:63)
#1 0x408ba3 sarf::verb::trilateral::augmented::AugmentedActivePastVerb::AugmentedActivePastVerb(this=0x69d580, r=0x6928e0, lDpa=..., cp=..., fn=7) (/home/yasser/projects/testv3z_augmented/verb/trilateral/augmented/active/AugmentedActivePastVerb.cpp:30)
#2 0x407214 sarf::verb::trilateral::augmented::AugmentedActivePastConjugator::createVerb(this=0x7fffffffe1af, root=0x6928e0, pronounIndex=0, formulaNo=7) (/home/yasser/projects/testv3z_augmented/verb/trilateral/augmented/active/AugmentedActivePastConjugator.cpp:27)
#3 0x40730a sarf::verb::trilateral::augmented::AugmentedActivePastConjugator::createVerbList(this=0x7fffffffe1af, root=0x6928e0, formulaNo=7) (/home/yasser/projects/testv3z_augmented/verb/trilateral/augmented/active/AugmentedActivePastConjugator.cpp:34)
#4 0x403295 testverb1() (/home/yasser/projects/testv3z_augmented/main.cpp:61)
#5 0x4034a8 main() (/home/yasser/projects/testv3z_augmented/main.cpp:83)
```

this is the base class, it is an abstract class to call the ConjugateInFormulaX() functions
.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include "AugmentedTrilateralRoot.h"

using namespace std;

namespace sarf
{
    namespace verb
    {
        namespace trilateral
        {
            namespace augmented
            {

                class AugmentedPastVerb
                {
                        typedef wstring (AugmentedPastVerb::*ConjugateFuns)();

                    protected:
                        AugmentedTrilateralRoot* root;

                        wstring resualt;

                        wstring lastDpa;

                        wstring connectedPronoun;

                        virtual wstring ConjugateInFormula1()=0;

                        virtual wstring ConjugateInFormula2()=0;

                        virtual wstring ConjugateInFormula3()=0;

                        virtual wstring ConjugateInFormula4()=0;

                        virtual wstring ConjugateInFormula5()=0;

                        virtual wstring ConjugateInFormula6()=0;

                        virtual wstring ConjugateInFormula7()=0;

                        virtual wstring ConjugateInFormula8()=0;

                        virtual wstring ConjugateInFormula9()=0;

                        virtual wstring ConjugateInFormula10()=0;

                        virtual wstring ConjugateInFormula12()=0;

                        ConjugateFuns ConjugateFunsList[12];

                    public:
                        AugmentedPastVerb() {}
                        AugmentedPastVerb(AugmentedTrilateralRoot* r, wstring lDpa, wstring cp,int fn);

                        inline wstring getConnectedPronoun()
                        {
                            return connectedPronoun;
                        }
                        inline AugmentedTrilateralRoot* getRoot()
                        {
                            return root;
                        }

                        inline wstring getLastDpa()
                        {
                            return lastDpa;
                        }

                        inline wstring toString()
                        {
                            return AugmentedPastVerb::resualt;
                        }
                };

            }
        }
    }
}
```

.cpp

```
#include "AugmentedPastVerb.h"


    using namespace std;

namespace sarf {namespace verb{namespace trilateral{namespace augmented{

     AugmentedPastVerb::AugmentedPastVerb(AugmentedTrilateralRoot* r, wstring lDpa, wstring cp,int fn)
     {
        ConjugateFunsList[0] = &AugmentedPastVerb::ConjugateInFormula1;
        ConjugateFunsList[1] = &AugmentedPastVerb::ConjugateInFormula2;
        ConjugateFunsList[2] = &AugmentedPastVerb::ConjugateInFormula3;
        ConjugateFunsList[3] = &AugmentedPastVerb::ConjugateInFormula4;
        ConjugateFunsList[4] = &AugmentedPastVerb::ConjugateInFormula5;
        ConjugateFunsList[5] = &AugmentedPastVerb::ConjugateInFormula6;
        ConjugateFunsList[6] = &AugmentedPastVerb::ConjugateInFormula7;
        ConjugateFunsList[7] = &AugmentedPastVerb::ConjugateInFormula8;
        ConjugateFunsList[8] = &AugmentedPastVerb::ConjugateInFormula9;
        ConjugateFunsList[9] = &AugmentedPastVerb::ConjugateInFormula10;
        ConjugateFunsList[10] = &AugmentedPastVerb::ConjugateInFormula11;
        ConjugateFunsList[11] = &AugmentedPastVerb::ConjugateInFormula12;

        root = r;
        lastDpa = lDpa;
        connectedPronoun = cp;
        //resualt = (this->*ConjugateFunsList[formulaNo])();
     }
}}}}
```

this class to hold root being conjugated
.h

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "AugmentationFormula.h"
#include "TrilateralRoot.h"

    using namespace std;
    using namespace sarf;

namespace sarf {namespace verb{namespace trilateral{namespace augmented{

class AugmentedTrilateralRoot : public TrilateralRoot{
private:
    wstring c1;
    wstring c2;
    wstring c3;

    vector<AugmentationFormula*> augmentations;

public:
    AugmentedTrilateralRoot(){}

    void addAugmentationFormula(AugmentationFormula* formula);

    virtual wstring getC1();
    virtual wstring getC2() ;
    virtual wstring getC3();

    vector<AugmentationFormula*> getAugmentationList();
    AugmentationFormula* getAugmentationFormula(int formulaNo) ;

    void setC1(wstring c1v) ;
    void setC2(wstring c2v);
    void setC3(wstring c3v) ;

};

}}}}
```

.cpp

```
#include "AugmentedTrilateralRoot.h"

using namespace std;

namespace sarf {namespace verb{namespace trilateral{namespace augmented{

    void AugmentedTrilateralRoot::addAugmentationFormula(AugmentationFormula* formula) {
        augmentations.push_back(formula);
    }

    wstring AugmentedTrilateralRoot::getC1() { return c1; }

    wstring AugmentedTrilateralRoot::getC2() { return c2; }

    wstring AugmentedTrilateralRoot::getC3() { return c3; }

    vector<AugmentationFormula*> AugmentedTrilateralRoot::getAugmentationList() {
        return augmentations;
    }

    AugmentationFormula* AugmentedTrilateralRoot::getAugmentationFormula(int formulaNo) {
        return augmentations[formulaNo];
    }

     void AugmentedTrilateralRoot::setC3(wstring c3v) {c3 = c3v;}

     void AugmentedTrilateralRoot::setC2(wstring c2v) {c2 = c2v;}

     void AugmentedTrilateralRoot::setC1(wstring c1v) {c1 = c1v;}

}}}}
```

Comment: Run it in a debugger (e.g. gdb) to find out where exactly the problem occurs and what the stack trace looks like at that moment.

Comment: Looking at the code you presented, there is a strong possibility that something goes wrong in the `root->getC1()` or `root->getC2()` calls. Are you sure `root` points to a valid object?

Comment: @jogojapan yes it points to a valid object

Comment: @jogojapan when I debug it in CodeBlocks I see that root have all its chars and ArabicHarakat are also valid, they all contain the chars that i assign to them

Comment: The debugger will tell you in what line it crashes. Is that the `return`-line in `ConjugateInFormula8()`, or a different one? Can you add the full stack trace to the question?

Comment: @jogojapan yes it's in ConjugateInFormula8()

Comment: Could you double check that the `AugmentedActivePastVerb` object for which you call the `ConjugateInFormula8()` method, is actually valid? The memory address for that object (`0x69d580`) looks suspicious (much shorter than the other ones -- could be for valid reasons, though).

Comment: Post `getC1()`, `getC2()`, `getC3()`. I suspect a dangling reference being returned but without code its impossible to confirm, particularly in light of this stmt: "...and **dynamic strings** returned by root.getCX()" (emphasis added).

Comment: @WhozCraig, I edited my Q with must needed code, the AugmentedActivePastVerb is just like AugmentedPastVerb but it implements the pure virtual functions from it, thanks

Comment: @jogojapan I commented code in ConjugateInFormula8() and used all the classes in that line all works expect AugmentedTrilateralRoot, although it gives me a valid address and values in the debuger, can you see whats going on in this class, thanks

Comment: But according to your call stack it fails in `AugmentedActivePastVerb`, not in `AugmentedTrilateralRoot`.